# Top navbar items cutting off picture below

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm using MaterializeCSS to style a website I am creating.

In order for me to get the navbar items to be towards the bottom of the navbar, I applied a top margin to those items (`#normal-nav`). As an unintended side effect, the picture below the navbar gets clipped for some reason. If I remove the margin that I applied to the `li`, then all is well. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[Here is the issue replicated in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62uebx9m/1/). In order for you to see the issue I'm having, you'll need to make the window rather large--I have it setup so those items only appear on desktop-sized displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the top-margin try :

```
#normal-nav {
    top: 64px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works over the `margin-top`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've pushed the #normal-nav down beyond its parent. This is exacerbated by the fact that it's a floated element, thus it doesn't increase the size of its container.

See: [An article about clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html)

**Solutions:**

1. Decreasing the the margin-top you're giving
2. Use a clearfix if you're intent on keeping the float.
3. Use another method other than float to push that nav to the right e.g. flexbox (probably the most scalable option).

Comment: I should have said I also tried doing `.nav-wrapper li` and adding a top margin to that--and I got the same end result. Thank you for the info about clearfix.